Does LLVM iterate over blocks in a fixed order?
I am using LLVM to iterator basic blocks in a Module.
The Module is parsed from a fixed IR file. The code is
for (const Function &F : *M)
        for (const BasicBlock &BB : F)
            for (const Instruction &I : BB){
......

}

I want to know:

Does LLVM give the same order of basic blocks when I execute the above program for multiple times?

Does LLVM give the same order of basic blocks after I instrument some non-branching instructions into some blocks ?



LLVM iterates in insertion order (unless you have code that explicitly reorders the list), so it may or may not be the same order next time you run the program: It depends on the code that creates the blocks.
Inserting instructions into a block doesn't affect the list of blocks, so your instrumentation won't reorder the blocks.

Thanks @arnt. I am not very clear about your first paragraph. Do you mean that, if I run my program for(const Function &F : *M)... for multiple times, I may get different order of blocks?

That for loop always iterates in insertion order. The insertion order need not be the same every time you run your program. Suppose you have some code that reads a file and inserts objects into an STL set in order to eliminate duplicates, then iterates over the set to create BasicBlock objects and insert them into a Function. In that case the set iteration happens in a different order each time you run the program.

@arnt That should be unordered_set, right?

Maybe… my memory is fuzzy and I don't remember which collection was involved. ASLR or something caused an STL collection to iterate in different orders each time.

Thanks @arnt. If I parse the same Module from reading the same bc file, does the order of blocks change in different runs?

It didn't change for me, with any of the LLVM versions I used. That's not a documented property of the LLVM Module reader though.
